# How can I add simple markup to localized texts in Blazor?

Tags: localization, blazor-server-side

I've followed all the instructions to get this text to be localized depending on chosen culture:

```
page "/demo"
@using System.Globalization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Program> Loc

<p>@Loc["LocalizedText"]</p>
```

But how can I add some bold words or similar harmless markup to this text?

Comment: Use `(MarkupString)`

Comment: Also, just add `<b> <b/>` tags around your text.